# Google Apps Marketplace: How can we find all the users in a customer's organization our app is authorized for?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts, google-directory-api

Our customer is installing our App Marketplace app for a particular sub-organization. How can we get a list of these users? Once we get that list (email addr), we can use service accounts to access their resources.
Also, is there any way to get the names of the organization units for which our app has permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the users in an OU using the Admin SDK Directory API's `Users.list()` endpoint. Pass in a query like `orgUnitPath=/ouNameHere` to filter the users to just the OU's you care about.

Unfortunately it currently isn't possible to access the OUs that your Apps Marketplace app has been enabled for.

Comment: So how does one go about finding the list of users that have access to your application on the customer domain?

Comment: I don't think there is a reliable way to do that today. You could keep track of all of the users that have opened your app, if you require a clear signal.